# Battlefield 3 Origin Install issues - error 262145:5

Tags: battlefield-3, origin

I recently picked up Battlefield 3 in a physical copy but have had issues with installing it.

Install steps so far:

1. Inserted disk 1, created an Origin account, and installed Origin. No issues.
2. Started the install, slow but progress was made. At around 70% it asked for the second disk.
3. Put in disk 2 (remember, new clean disk) and it progressed to around 85% before saying the disk could not be read.
4. Gave the disk a quick clean, tried a couple more times with no luck.
5. Origin gave me the option of downloading the game instead. Hoping that it would use the files previously copied over from the disk. Nope. Looks like it was downloading the whole 16GB.
6. Cancelled the download.
7. Copied the content of both DVDs to a local hard disk and tried to install from there.
8. Same issue - guess a problem with disk 2.
9. Extracted the content from the disks and pasted them in my C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin\Origin Game\Battlefield 3 and started the download again.
10. Files downloaded slowley and then jumped from a couple of MB to over 11GB (guess it found the files from the disk?)
11. Managed to download another 4GB of files through Origin.
12. Have now go to the stage where I regularly get an error message (around 95%) "An unexpected error has occoured. Please try again in a few minutes. Error 262145:5"

262145:5 seems to be an error code not limited to Battlefield 3, but apart from that I can't find much out.

My question here, then, is what are my options? I've heard horror stories about EA's Origin support and would rather not spend an evening trying to talk to someone. I have a couple of friends with Battlefield 3 so could probably use their disks, or copy their install (if that would work). Or I could keep trying and hope it's an issue with Origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, I'm not sure if this actually will work.
But the only thing I would recommend to try is to uninstall and install again.

1. Open Origin
2. Right click on the Battlefield 3 cover in Origin
3. The option lowest in the drop menu should be "Uninstall". Click that.
4. When it have uninstalled, try reinstall completely from Origin, no disks.

To download from Origin:

1. Click on the cover of Battlefield 3.
2. A drop menu should appear, giving you the option to "Install".

I hope this will work for you :)
And if it does, i wish you luck on the battlefield!

Comment: I've kicked off a Origin install...however 16GB is not going to be quick, hence me buying a physical copy.

Comment: Origin install finished without issues. Anybody that does get the rather cryptic error message I would advise they do a full download and I hope you don't have data caps.

Comment: What about for those of us who can't download 16 GB in ~8 hours?

Answer (score 4):

The other answers should fix the problem, but you will lose **all** the progress you had once.

This problem is caused when your client (Origin Downloader) downloads some corrupted files. Everytime you restart a download, Origin try to open ALL the files to get their CRC's, but these corrupted files has wrong CRC's. So you must delete all these corrupted files that are listed in a LOG file.

Do this:

1. Go to `C:\ProgramData\Origin\Logs` and open `Client_Log.html`
2. Open it in your browser
3. Sroll next to the end of the file, and look for some red phrases saying something like

   > Error opening file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin Games\Battlefield 3\Core\EACore.dll". (5)

So I had to delete the `EACore.dll`, and other files listed together.

If there is more files listed, delete them all and repeat the process until Origin can start downloading fine. That would be sad if some very large files were corrupted, but I had luck.

Answer (score 2):

I do believe I've found a slight fix for part of this. If you have only installed some of BF3 via disc, then you can allow the download to carry on from where it stopped by:

1. Making sure that the download folder `XX:\programfiles(x86)/origingames` is the same spot where you first installed half of BF3. For example, if you installed half of it on the D drive but it was originally was on the C drive, Origin would automatically think that all DOWNLOADED (not installed via disc) games should go to the C drive. Therefore, you would want to change this to the D drive instead.  You can do this by going to the top left 'Origin' tab - Application Settings - Downloaded Games, and then just change the folder.
2. If you are successful, when you click download, it should just carry on from where it stopped!

Note: If you had stopped the installation midway, it might cause a file to be corrupted. You can fix this by right clicking on the game and choosing 'repair install'

Answer (score 0):

Delete everything in the battlefield directory except the DATA directory (which contains all the large files). Then in the Origin program in main menu click Origin -> Reload my games. Your download will continue at 61%.

Answer (score 0):

For me works this: delete all files in main game folder, and Core directory. Then rest of the download process will take another few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

i had BAttle Field 3 Prompting to Download Issue, I found this Article Useful to Fix it Out... Here is the Link

http://www.ign.com/blogs/christina.john/2013/08/29/fix-battlefield-3-prompting-to-download/

Answer (score 0):

I just thought I would throw in an alternative answer. I just updated Origin to the latest version, having run it for the first time since I upgraded to Windows 8.1. I was encountering **Error 262145:5** on all my downloads (initial downloads, so I had no existing folders on my hard drives to delete, indicating that the other answers to this question did not apply). When I exited, Windows popped up that familiar "Did this program run correctly?" dialog, and I ran through it.

After a couple test runs, Windows determined that the application needed to be *run as Administrator*, using the *Windows Vista (SP2) compatibility mode*. Once I reached that config, downloading worked. I've been able to download and install all of my games now that the Windows compatibility settings are set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you log into Origin on their website, find BF3 on the online store, then click "Play on Origin", it will prompt you to open with the application. There you can choose Origin, and the download will work.

Answer (score -3):

i found the solution , look : cut your battlefield folder from origin's games folder , and put somewhere, and then start downloading, and after downloading about 20 Mo stop it and go into your battlefeild's folder and cut : core+data+update and put it into origin's games again , and start downloading again , and have fun ^_^